# Добавить компонент на PaintBox

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Я создаю приложение в `delphi 7` с использование `KOL/MCK`. Проблема в том, что я не могу добавить компонент (будь то label, button и т.д.) на `PaintBox`.

Когда я только создал `PaintBox`, то я спокойно мог на него добавлять компоненты, а сейчас почему-то нет.

У меня `PaintBox` растянуть на всю форму и получается когда я добавляю компонент, то компонент относиться к `Form1`, а не к `PaintBox`. В итоге компонента вообще не видно.

Comment: пробуйте этим компонентам (метке, кнопке) поменять owner'а на paintbox. Можно в objectInspector, можно и прямо в коде.

Answer (score 1):

Делаете так:
Кладете `TGroupBox`, внутри него размещаете `TPaintBox` с `Align - alClient`, 
в `run-time`, в нужный момент, циклом `for`, меняете родителя нужных компонент на свой.

Примерно так:

```
with GroupBox1 do
begin
  for i:=0 to ControlCount - 1 do
  begin
   if (Controls[i] is TLabel) then
   (Controls[i] is TLabel).Parent:=MyPaintBox;
  ...
  end;
end;
```

`TGroupBox` нужен если форме, если будут др. компоненты, которым не надо ничего менять, никогда.